# Modify number of shifts in a day in nurse rostering example

Tags: optaplanner

i am new to optaplanner, i am working on nurse rostering example in optaplanner.
i am trying to modify number of shifts in a single day, i tried changing value in the unsolved dataset i.e. JavaScript file, but nothing getting updated in the final results.
For each day the number of shifts required are predefined in the JS file, i try changing value of Required Employees size, but its not changing.
i want to modify number of shifts constraints in a day.
how can i modify.

Thanks in advance.